# Understanding syntax for CalculateField_management in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, error-000989

I need to use CalculateField_management in a Python script, and the calc expression needs to concatenate a runtime variable, a string, and a field (string) value.  I have searched all over for examples from which to learn.  I have tried many things I have found in my research and some of my own ideas, too, but I just can't get the calc expression to evaluate.  I am now completely confused and need some help to dig out of this hole.  So, here's the scoop.

The field to be calculated, DESCRIP, is a string field in a fGDB feature class with one feature.  The runtime variable, *enddesg*, will be a string.  Essentially, what I want to do is concatenate the runtime value with a (longish) string and prepend that to the existing value in the DESCRIP field, storing the result back in the DESCRIP field.  I have tried many forms of an "all-in-one" string for the expression, but nothing worked.  I came to the conclusion that a pre-logic approach would be better, but I haven't been able to get that to work either.  Below is what I have right now.

```
expr = "getDescription(str(enddesg))"
codeblock = """def getDescription(endstr):
    exprstr = endstr + ' Touchdown Zone Elevation;duplicated from existing control point;' + !DESCRIP!
    return exprstr"""
arcpy.CalculateField_management(perpptsSX_src, "DESCRIP", expr, 'PYTHON_9.3', codeblock)  #Should be only one feature in the source
```

(BTW, the *enddesg* variable is either a string or an integer but is converted to a string as input.)  I get the following error:

```
<class 'arcgisscripting.ExecuteError'>: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (line 2)

Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

The following code variation produces no errors, but I also get nothing entered in the DESCRIP field.

```
expr = "getDescription(str(enddesg), !DESCRIP!)"
codeblock = """def getDescription(endstr, desc):
    exprstr = endstr + ' Touchdown Zone Elevation;duplicated from existing control point;' + desc
    return exprstr"""
```

I am now thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I never understand why people even try to mess with `CalculateField_management` within a Python script instead of just doing their updates within an [`UpdateCursor`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000003m000000.htm).

Not only do you not have to worry about escaping characters and writing Python functions within Python strings (shudder), you can update multiple fields at once.

It's very easy with the newer arcpy cursor iteration syntax:

```
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
    row.DESCRIP = "%s Touchdown Zone Elevation;duplicated from existing control point;%s" % (str(enddesg), row.DESCRIP)
    rows.updateRow(row)
del rows
```

The magic on the `row.DESCRIP =` line is called [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) in Python -- in this case it wasn't that necessary but when you're concatenating more than a couple of strings or need some specific numeric formatting it's really handy.

The other thing to note is that instead of hardcoding the field name (`row.DESCRIP`) you can also get and set field values using a variable to specify the field using [`row.getValue` and `row.setValue`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000.htm) instead.

For the most part, I would suggest using `getValue` and `setValue` as it makes your code much easier to maintain if the field name changes or you want to write a generic function or script tool with the field name(s) as parameters.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I usually avoid Update Cursors, because performance can be so abysmal on large datasets.  I am normally working with very large datasets, and it just didn't click with me that, in this case, speed just isn't an issue.  The update cursor method worked fine, of course, and I shall move on.  Just for my own edification, though, I really would like to find out the solution to using CalculateField.  I do work with complex legacy scripts that need updating now and again.  The knowledge would be helpful.  Thanks, again, all.

Comment: Cursors are slow and smelly. :( And besides, you can use string substitution just as easily in a codeblock, can you not?

Comment: @Nathanus, I've never noticed any performance issues with UpdateCursors but in 10.1 they are supposed to be faster. I would be interested in seeing if anyone has timed the two with varying size tables. And sure you can do string substitution in a function written in the code block of CalculateValue, but I find doing so is less maintainable and readable and just all around a PITA compared to doing it with a cursor. You would need to do CalculateValue once for each field which is surely going to be slower than an cursor that updates multiple fields at once.

Comment: *correction* CalculateField where I said CalculateValue -- darn 5 minute edit limit!

Comment: This looks indeed likes a much cleaner then using calculateField in python. Due to the claims of the abysmal performance on large datasets I decided to test it myself.

Comment: This looks much cleaner than using calculateField. Due to the claims of the abysmal performance on large datasets I did some fast tests. I did a calculateField and updateCursor on a dataset with about 90000 values. The function reads from one field, does something with it and writes to an other field. calculateField took about 26s, updateCursor did it 10 times slower, 260s! So if you care about performance, choose calculateField. Remark: calculateField will skip null value fields, updateCursor iterators over all the rows, so the semantics of both functions are not exactly the same! 5min edit.

Comment: That seems bad indeed, and probably why they say are improving cursor speeds in 10.1. I wonder though if setting the `fields` argument to the UpdateCursor to limit it to the one field you are reading will result in a significant performance boost.

Comment: @tmske nice research. I still suspect blah238 is right when multi-field updates are involved, however considering the values you posted, there may be a threshold of like 3 or 4 fields before the savings start to reveal themselves.

Comment: @elrobis I'm not sure if the performance still holds for 10.x, so be sure to test it first if you want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, but I believe you are not supposed to put the field name `!DESCRIP!` in the code block. Use a placeholder variable and it should function properly.

Comment: Yup. `!field!` only works in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

In my testing, calling str() on an argument in your expression causes the tool to fail. Maybe try:

```
expr = "getDescription(enddesg, !DESCRIP!)"
codeblock = """def getDescription(endstr, desc):
    exprstr = str(endstr) + ' Touchdown Zone Elevation;duplicated from existing control point;' + desc
    return exprstr"""
```

Comment: Why not convert it to a string inside the codeblock so that it can concatenate happily?

Comment: @Nathanus that should work :-), I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: @Derek Swingley - I thought it would work, too ... until it didn't.  Same result.  No errors, just nothing entered into the DESCRIP field.  I did try converting the _enddesg_ variable to a string before the expression statement and just passing in the string:  no converting in either the expression statement or the codeblock.  Still the same result.  Hmmm.  I shall continue to pound on this, but I would appreciate any further thoughts any of you may have.

Comment: UPDATE - I tried the above code in the Field Calculator (with the variation of `getDescription('10', !DESCRIP!)` for testing on a single feature), and it worked just fine.  So, the logic is fine, but there is something funky about how the code is passed to and interpreted in the CalculateField_management tool.  I think it must have something to do with how things are quoted.  Any thoughts?